# WCF facility : Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

I asked this before and got no where so i'm asking again as i'm now desperate!!

Hey

if i create a new wcf project i can browse the meta instantly.

if I try - when using the WCF facility - i get the following:

Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

i followed the instructions there and in a million other places and get no where.

if i copy the contents of my faciltity service into the newly created project it complains that aspNetCompatibilityEnabled isnt enabled.

so i enable it and then mex is disabled again and i get: Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

again!!

this is driving me crazy - i have tried tried tried to follow every example on the web!!

here is my current configuration - there is no client yet:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <services>
            <service name="IbzStar.WebServices.UserServices" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IbzStar.WebServices.IUserServices">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

please someone help me out before my laptop gets launched into orbit!!

w://

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to make sure that service name, interface and config definitions are defined correctly. check for mis-match in names etc. Better to define configuration from scratch rather than identifying mistakes.